# Generic deserialization in kafka

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization

I have two classes for serialization and deserialization in kafka. Serialization work fine but I have problem with deserialization.

I found many solutions, but nothing works.

Deserializer with generic class T

```
public class DeserializerU<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

@Override
public void configure(Map map, boolean bln) {
}

@Override
public void close() {
}

@Override
public T deserialize(String string, byte[] bytes) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T object = null;
    try {
      object = mapper.readValue(bytes, new TypeReference<T>() {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

Serializer

```
public class MyObjectSerializer implements Serializer {

@Override
public void configure(Map map, boolean bln) {
}

@Override
public byte[] serialize(String string, Object t) {
    byte[] retVal = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t).getBytes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal;
}

@Override
public void close() {   
}
```

Properties set deserializer

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, new DeserializerU<MyOwnObject>().getClass());
```

If I replace "TypeRefence(){}" for specific type then deserializer works but i need deserializer for many objects. I also tried convertValue instead of readValue but everything return LinkedHashMap which cannot be converted to my object. Any advice on how to do this?
Thanks for help

Comment: Spring-Kafka already has JSON serializers. Why write your own?

Comment: @erik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511256/how-to-implement-generic-kafka-streams-deserializer

Comment: I don't use Sping-Kafka :) basically we don't use spring at all. That's why I write our own.

Answer (score 1):

In your KafkaListenerContainerFactory set the message converter with a JsonMessageConverter. Look that in my config I don't specify any custom class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most underrated yet most accurate answer. I have spent hours creating custom deserializers, then trying to create a generic deserializer but nothing worked perfectly. Thanks @Vinicius Durate

Answer (score 0):

my answer might be later, but, can help someone.

With this, I do not need to create a ConsumerFactory for every topic, and, I can parse the json if necessary.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic...}")
public void consume(MyObject message) { ... }
```

without the need to create a JsonDeserializer for every object.

My CustomDeserializer Class:

```
@Component
public class CustomJsonDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    // This MAP maps the topic to the class that I need to convert.
    private final Map<String, Class<?>> maps; 

    public CustomJsonDeserializer(
            // I can access the application properties that were defined
            final Environment environment,
            final ObjectMapper mapper
    ) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        maps = new HashMap<>(2);
        maps.put(environment.getProperty("my-topic-1"), MyClass1.class);
        maps.put(environment.getProperty("my-topic-2"), MyClass2.class);

    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        if (Objects.isNull(data) || data.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(data, target);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

My KafkaConfiguration class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    // You need to create a bean of ObjectMapper, so, spring can inject it into here
    @Autowired
    private CustomJsonDeserializer customJsonDeserializer;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        final var properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(6);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Object>(properties, new StringDeserializer(), customJsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        final var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Then, on my consumers, I can write:
MyConsumers.java

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${my-topic-1}")
    public void consume(final MyClass1 item) {
        //Do what whatever you want
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${my-topic-2}")
    public void consume(final MyClass2 item) {
        //Do what whatever you want
    }
```

Comment: Spring-kafka deserializer natively supports multiple types now

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Kafka properties are like this

```
exampe.kafka.deserializer.mapper =com.example.consumer.model.Example
```

```java
public class DeserializerU<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

private Class<T> type;

@Override
public void configure(Map map, boolean bln) {
   this.type = (Class) map.get("example.kafka.deserializer.mapper");
}

@Override
public void close() {
}

@Override
public T deserialize(String string, byte[] bytes) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T object = null;
    try {
      object = mapper.readValue(bytes, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
}
```

Comment: You should not create a new ObjectMapper for every record. Also note that Spring Kafka, for example, already has a json deserializer

Comment: yap, correct we should not need create a new ObjectMapper for every record

I'm just following the author's code